# Ruby - Clear all the global variables

Tags: ruby

I am using an existing framework for parallel execution. There are so many global variables being used in this. I could see some of the global variables (yes, we should avoid it, but in this case, I don't have an option) are creating issues. *global_variables* shows the list of all the global variables used. I want to clear them at the end of every execution. Any suggestions, please? ((

Comment: The best thing you could do is not creating them in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some early point in your program, record the global variables that are provided by the Ruby interpreter itself and store that it in a constant:

```rb
OrigGlobalVars = global_variables
```

I don't think there is a way to undefine global variables, but you can set all the new ones created by your code to `nil` by doing this:

```rb
(global_variables - OrigGlobalVars).each { |g| eval "#{g} = nil" }
```

This certainly might break some code that uses the global variables, because the code might not be designed to gracefully handle the case where the variable is nil.  But you can fix those cases as they come up.

Comment: If this answers your question, please click the checkmark to accept it.  Or at least upvote it.

Comment: Yes David, I already tried that. When I try to upvote any answer, I am getting the error message "You need at least 15 reputations to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." Sorry about this.

Comment: Checkmark worked !  ))

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

You don't want to clear *all* globals, as Ruby depends on a number of global variables and constants for proper operation. It's okay to clear the ones you've defined, though.

However, you can't actually *undefine* globals, although you can certainly re-assign their values. Refactoring to namespaced or lexically-scoped variables should be a longer term objective, even if the suggestions below work for you now. There are *many* options for passing bindings, values, configuration settings, and object references that don't rely on globals, and reducing variable scope is *usually* the right thing to do in most cases.

That said, here are some suggestions that may help with your situation. I've also noted some edge cases that may or may not apply to your code, but that should be in the back of your mind when dealing with top-level bindings and global namespaces.

### You Can't Undefine or Garbage-Collect Globals

By definition, global variables never go out of scope. That also means the variables themselves can never be garbage-collected either.

Additionally, similarly to instance variables but unlike class or local variables, global variables are auto-vivified<sup>*</sup> as `nil` when referenced to prevent NameError. Even if you never actually define *$foo*, `$foo == nil #=> true`.

---

<sup>*</sup>As a subtle distinction, `defined? $foo #=> nil` while `$foo = nil; defined? $foo #=> "global-variable"`, but I don't think that has any practical bearing on your question.

---

If your primary goal is just to "unset" the values of your globals, you can do something like:

```
NILABLE_GLOBALS = %w[$foo $bar $baz]
NILABLE_GLOBALS.map { eval "#{_1} = nil" }
```

While the variables are all still technically defined, pragmatically they will respond similarly to being undefined, e.g. by being equal to `nil`.

#### Reducing Memory Consumed by Globals

This approach may also minimize the memory footprint of the globals by pointing them all to what amounts to a singleton object, e.g. the sole instance of NilClass. This should reduce memory usage *if* the values previously stored in your globals are garbage collected when nothing references them any longer. There are perhaps several edge cases, like frozen strings stored in the TOPLEVEL_BINDING, where I'm unsure if the values will truly lose all references and thus be garbage collected, but that's more of a memory management issue than a value assignment or object identity issue, and if memory were a primary concern you wouldn't be using globals in the first place.

So long as you aren't relying on `defined?` returning `nil` when the values are reset, this seems like your best option short of refactoring your code to use variables that can go out of scope.

##### Additional Caveats

If you're using a much older version of Ruby that can't garbage-collect Symbols, assign String objects to your globals when you can. You might also disable frozen strings as a default if you find that they aren't being garbage collected even when no longer referenced. You can inspect [ObjectSpace](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/ObjectSpace.html) after calling the [GC module](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/GC.html) to look for unwanted Symbol and String objects if memory bloats excessively. While these are unlikely to be real problems for you, at least you have a starting point if they are.

Comment: "That also means the variables themselves can never be garbage-collected either." – That doesn't have anything to do with them being *global* variables, however. *No* variables can be garbage-collected in Ruby because only objects can be garbage-collected, and variables aren't objects. This is also not specific to Ruby. In almost all programming languages, variables are not objects themselves.

Comment: @JörgWMittag If you define a variable that can go out of scope, the variable name itself (not just its value) can be swept because it is no longer referenced or tracked. If you can show real code where an *unreferenced* non-global variable's name is immune to GC and remains tracked by the mainline VM after garbage collection I will modify my answer. Otherwise, you're claiming that variable names are "forever" in the same way that Symbol objects used to be immune before improvements to GC were made.

Comment: "you're claiming that variable names are "forever"" – No, I am claiming that the concept of "garbage collection", which is about reclaiming memory used by objects is simply not applicable at all to variables, because variables are not objects and thus are not occupying any memory in the object space that could be reclaimed. I cannot show any piece of code that demonstrates that, precisely because variables are not objects and Ruby code can only deal with objects, not with things that are not objects. Similarly, I cannot show any code that demonstrates that the `end` keyword isn't garbage …

Comment: … collected because the `end` keyword is not an object and thus it is impossible to write a program that interacts with it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag In Ruby, all accessible variables names are tracked through various data structures including (but perhaps not limited to) Binding objects, ObjectSpace,  and presumably pointers or other references in the underlying C code. I *do* understand what you are trying to say here, but in the C implementation of Ruby, variable names are stored when accessible and removed when no longer accessible. If you want to call that something other than GC that seems to be splitting hairs rather finely. It's bike-shedding unless you can show a *pragmatic* distinction other than terminology.